# pyspark: expand a DenseVector to tuple in a RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following RDD, each record is a tuple of (bigint, vector):

```
myRDD.take(5)

[(1, DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432])),
 (1, DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432])),
 (0, DenseVector([5.0, 20.0, 0.3444, 0.3295, 54.3122, 4.0])),
 (1, DenseVector([9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432])),
 (1, DenseVector([9.2463, 2.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432]))]
```

How do I expand the Dense vector and make it part of a tuple? i.e. I want the above to become:

```
[(1, 9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432),
 (1, 9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432),
 (0, 5.0, 20.0, 0.3444, 0.3295, 54.3122, 4.0),
 (1, 9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432),
 (1, 9.2463, 2.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: A hint: `Vector` is iterable. Everything else is a rudimentary Python (arguments unpacking may be useful but not necessary).

Comment: Thanks zero323! I tried newRDD = myRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],tuple(x[1]))) , it does expand the DenseVector into a tuple, but I still got a tuple inside a tuple like: (1, (1, 9.2463, 1.0, 0.392, 0.3381, 162.6437, 7.9432)), any hint in flatting this nested tuple into one tuple? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` (or `mllib`) is iterbale (provide `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods) you can treat it like any other python collections, for example:

```
def as_tuple(kv):
    """
    >>> as_tuple((1, DenseVector([9.25, 1.0, 0.31, 0.31, 162.37])))
    (1, 9.25, 1.0, 0.31, 0.31, 162.37)
    """
    k, v = kv
    # Use *v.toArray() if you want to support Sparse one as well.
    return (k, *v)
```

For Python 2 replace:

```
(k, *v)
```

with:

```
from itertools import chain

tuple(chain([k], v))
```

or:

```
(k, ) + tuple(v)
```

If you want to convert values to Python (not NumPy) scalars use:

```
v.toArray().tolist()
```

in place of `v`.

Comment: `k,v = kv` is a structure unpacking. You could use `kv[0]`, `kv[1]` instead but if find it much more elegant and easier to read.